# How to fix "A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree." error in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building a fluter app with dismissible widget, firebase and StreamBuilder and getting following error "A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree."

Please find the below code sniped for the same.

```
Expanded(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                        .document('/users/User1/Trips/${widget.tripId}')
                        .collection('TropDocs')
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading....");
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemExtent: 150.0,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

final item = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                          final itemID =
                              snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID;
                          final list = snapshot.data.documents;      
return Dismissible(
   key: Key(itemID),
              // We also need to provide a function that tells our app
              // what to do after an item has been swiped away.
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                // Remove the item from our data source.

                //fBtDoc.deleteTraveldoc(item);
                //Firestore.instance.collection('/users/User1/Trips/${widget.tripId}/TropDocs/').document('$itemID').delete();
                setState(() {
                  list.removeAt(index);
                });

                // Then show a snackbar!
                Scaffold.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$item dismissed")));
              },
              // Show a red background as the item is swiped away
              background: Container(color: Colors.red),
              child: _buildlistitem(
                            context, snapshot.data.documents[index])
);

                        }
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 86):

Probably, I'm late, but I think it will be helpful for others. Had the same problem and even setting

```
key: Key(itemId[index]),
```

didn't work. However,

```
key: UniqueKey(),
```

worked perfectly for me

Comment: And do you have any explanation why **key: Key(itemId[index]),** is not working?
I have the same issue:
              **//key: ValueKey(widget.users[i].id), - is not working properly<br/>
              key: UniqueKey(), // does the trick**
And I'm tryong to figure out what is wrong with **ValueKey(userID)** providing that the user ID is coming from the DB and is unique of course...
I do understand why **UniqueKey()** works but have feeling that something related to **ValueKey** (based on loop index not directly) eludes me.

Comment: Well, after further investigation/debugging I found out that during list rebuilding, the dismissed item is still there! Its widget won't be visible, but the item(model) itself still exists in the list...
 Why - that's another question and I have resolved it properly in onDismissed. 
But it's important to realize that using UniqueKey() in such cases is just a workaround which recreates all the elements behind widgets. It seems working but may be more costly... Actuall removal should be performed before the first rebuild of the item widgets...

Comment: The problem with setting the key based on the index is that if you delete any item but the last, the index will still be there, because the next index in line will simply take up its place. item[0], item[1], item [2] -> if you delete item[1] the list will still contain item[1] (item[0], item [1]) because of the incremental nature of an indexed list. To verify this simply try to delete the last item of the list. Whereas every other item through an Exception this one did not. HOWEVER, using the ID of an item actually should work. Can you test, if deleting the last item works without an error?

Answer (score 16):

In my cause, I have used as below

```
key: Key(index),
```

and then I did change it as below. It's working

```
key: UniqueKey(),
```

Answer (score 15):

I think that's because you are trying to use same `key` for every dismissible.

`key: Key(itemID)`

It should be `key: Key(itemID[index])`

Answer (score 13):

The reason is that the value passed to the key property isn’t unique or related to the index of a list.
The solution is quite simple and all you need to do is set the key property to UniqueKey(), like this:

```
key: UniqueKey(),
```

Answer (score 8):

Remove setState block, streamBuilder will rebuild list by itself

```
 setState(() {
   list.removeAt(index);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Why giving index as key not working**

`key: Key(index)` : in this case the widget in widget tree will be bind in to the key which is the index , when you remove an item from the tree the build method will  re-run and it looks for the widget with the key is there and always it can find the index there as the next element in the list will be replaced by the current item with "same index"
that is why you are not getting this error when you try to remove it from end of the list the index can't be replaced because there is no element after this
so instead of using index as key use something unique in that element like the id of element or `UniqueKey()`

`key: Key(index)` will throw error

### use

`key: Key(item.id),`
or
`key: UniqueKey(),`

Answer (score 3):

**I'am also fall this error & debug with the following logic**
Instead of

```
key: Key(itemID),
```

use

```
key: Key(itemID[itemIDIndex]),
```

and in your setstae logic replace

```
setState(() {
              list.removeAt(index);
            });
```

with

```
setState(() {
              itemID.removeAt(itemIDIndex);
            });
```

this will solve the problem.

For reference see the Image Screenshot
[image: Item builder]
[image: remove at index here]

Answer (score 1):

I would have done something like this to remove swiping from right to left

```
                        confirmDismiss: (direction) {
                      return Future.value(direction == DismissDirection.endToStart);
                    },
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      setState(() {
                        list.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for a single widget dismissible is shown below and for the dismissible in a list write logic according to the code provided. Here we put an if condition for the Dismissible and in `onDismissed` just set that bool variable to false so that it will not remains in the widget tree.

```
if (_boolVariable)
 Dismissible(
    key: Key('anyString'),
    onDismissed: (direction) {
      //your code here
      setState(() => _boolVariable = false);
    },
  child: YourWidget())
```

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me

```
key: UniqueKey(),
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change remove(index) function under onDismissed: like that;

```
 ***- mylist.removeAt(index);***
```

Because, remove function removes items. And yo dismissed nothing but looks dismissed and trows error : A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.

```
***- so must be declared like this : mylist.remove(item);***
```

Answer (score 0):

### My problem

I have had a similar problem, but a little bit more complex. I wanted to use `ReordableListView` with `ListTile`'s along with `Dismissible`.

### My code

```
Container(
  child: ReorderableListView.builder(
    onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
    itemCount: _savedLocations.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      LocationModel? locationItem = _savedLocations?[index];
        return Dismissible(
        // key: UniqueKey(),
        // key: Key('$index'),
        key: Key('${locationItem?.id}'),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          LocationModel dismissed = _savedLocations[index];
          setState(() { _savedLocations.removeAt(index); });
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Location: $dismissedValue dismissed')));
        },
        child: ListTile(
          // key: Key('$index'),
          // key: UniqueKey(),
          key: ValueKey('${locationItem?.id}'),
          title: Text(locationItem?.name ?? ''),
          subtitle: Text(locationItem?.country ?? ''),
        ),
    ),
),
```

### Detailed explanation

I have started with `ListTile` and added `key: Key('$index')`, everything was working as expected. Then I wanted to add dismiss functionality so I wrapped it in `Dismissible`. `Dismissible` item also expect unique key, but I found out that actions on items with `key: UniqueKey()` assigned stopped working (dragging, dismissible).

**Note:** I have left commented out lines with wrong keys. For example: `Key('$index')` cannot be used for `Dismissible` because it will be deleted at the time of dismissal and causes error. I strongly suggest you to try it and see the error when trying to dismiss list item by swiping left or right.

### Solution

Solution was to set `Dismissible` key to unique item `Key('${locationItem?.id}')` and `ListTile` key to `ValueKey('${locationItem?.id}')`. In this is case both Drag&drop (reordable) and dismissible funcionality work as expected.

#### Hope it helps

Reference: [How to use ReorderableListView with DismissDirection in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860457/how-to-use-reorderablelistview-with-dismissdirection-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to avoid using setState. Dismissible, by default, utilizes the removeAt feature, and it requires that keys be unique.

The issue arises when removeAt removes an element from a specific index, causing the remaining elements to shift, resulting in non-unique keys. This is the reason for encountering this error.

```
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Peach'];
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: fruits.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Dismissible(
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                  fruits.removeAt(index);
                } else {
                  fruits.add(fruits[index].toString());
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(fruits[index])));
                }
              },
              background: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              secondaryBackground: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              key: Key(fruits[index]),
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                  title: Text(fruits[index]),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```